# multidimensional array (nested loop) does not function properly and returns duplicate incorrect results

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a two-dimensional array (nested loop) that compares two lists, correct format and wrong format using the hamming distance in which if the difference between the strings in the correct and wrong format = 1 it adds the correct format to a third list "corrected" and removes the worng formated string from the wrong format list.

the data inside the lists looks like this

```py
['BWI0520BG6,ATT7791R,AMS,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',
 'BWI0520BG6,BER7172M,KUL,LAS,1420565167,1848\n',]
```

so I have to slice it to get each part of the list to compare between the correct and wrong lists

the code used to compare between them

```py
corrected = []
correct_format = ['EZC9678QI6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'EZC9678QI6,RUM0422W,MUC,MAD,1420563539,194\n',
 'CKZ3132BR4,XXQ4064B,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'HCA3158QA6,GMO5938W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'JBE2302VO4,VDC9164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'XFG5747ZT9,PME8178S,DEN,PEK,1420564409,1322\n',
 'CDC0302NN5,QHU1140O,CDG,LAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'CYJ0225CH1,YZO4444S,BKK,MIA,1420565330,2027\n',
 'PIT2755XC1,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'IEG9308EA5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'LLZ3798PE3,ULZ8130D,CAN,DFW,1420564983,1683\n',
 'LLZ3798PE3,MBA8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n', 
 'PIT2755XC1,SOH3431A,ORD,MIA,1420563649,250\n',
 'XFG5747ZT9,XXQ4064B,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'HCA3158QA6,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'JBE2302VO4,HZT2506M,IAH,AMS,1420564324,1044\n',
 'VZY2993ME1,WSK1289Z,CLT,DEN,1420563542,278\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,TMV7633W,UGK,DXB,1420563958,849\n',
 'EDV2089LK5,ATT7791R,AMS,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',
 'SPR4484HA6,VDC9164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'UES9151GS5,DAU2617A,CGK,SFO,1420564986,1811\n',
 'WBE6935NU3,KJR6646J,IAH,BKK,1420565203,1928\n',  
 'CDC0302NN5,XIL3623J,PEK,LAX,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYU2010YH8,JVY9791G,PVG,FCO,1420564561,1189\n']

wrong_format = ['BWI0520BG6,VYW5940P,LAS,SI|,1420565203,1843\n',
 'CKZ3132BR4,RUM0422W,MUC,;AD,1420563539,194\n',
 'CKZ313\\BR4,QHU1140O,CDG,LAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,GMO593[W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,VDCP164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'DAZ3029XA0,WPW9201U,DFW,yEK,1420564869,1452\n',
 'HGO4350KK1,QHU1140O,CDG,vAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'JJM4724RF7,YZO4444S,BKK,MI^,1420565330,2027\n',
 'KKP5277HZ7,VYW5940P,LAS,:IN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'MXU9187YC7,MOO1786A,MAD,]RA,1420563408,184\n',
 'ONL0812DH1,BER7172M,KUL,[AS,1420565167,1848\n',
 'PAJ3974RK1,EWH6301Y,~AN,DFW,1420564967,1683\n',
 'POP2875LH3,MBw8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,SOH3431A,OR8,MIA,1420563649,250\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,XXQ4064%,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,4QU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,HZT2506M,IAH,#MS,1420564324,1044\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,WSK1289Z,CLT,vEN,1420563542,278\n',
 'SJD8|75RZ4,ULZ8130D,CAN,DFW,1420564983,1683\n',
 'SPR4484HA6,ATT7791R,AM%,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',
 'SPRb484HA6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'UES915*GS5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'WBE6935NU$,XOY7948U,ATL,LHR,1420564038,877\n',
 'WTC9125IE5,XIL3623J,PEK,L}X,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYU2010YH8,XIL3623J,PEe,LAX,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYu2010YH8,FYL5866L,ATL,HKG,1420565140,1751\n',
 'YMH6360YP0,ATT7791R,A;S,DEN,1420564394,1001\n']

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))

for r in correct_format:
    for i in wrong_format:
        if hamming_distance(r[0:10], i[0:10]) == 1:      
            corrected.append(r)
            wrong_format.remove(i)
        elif hamming_distance(r[11:19], i[11:19]) == 1:
            corrected.append(r)
            wrong_format.remove(i)
        elif hamming_distance(r[20:23], i[20:23]) == 1:
            corrected.append(r)
            wrong_format.remove(i)
        elif hamming_distance(r[24:27], i[24:27]) == 1:
            corrected.append(r)
            wrong_format.remove(i)
```

So, the corrected list is expected to be filled with the correct format and the wrong format should be empty

```py
corrected  = ['POP2875LH3,MBW8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n',
 'UES9157GS5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,GMO5937W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,BQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,XXQ4064X,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,ULZ8130D,CAN,DFW,1420564983,1683\n',
 'ONL0812DH1,BER7172M,KUL,LAS,1420565167,1848\n',
 'YMH6360YP0,ATT7791R,AMS,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',]
```

However, this is what I get

```py
corrected  = ['POP2875LH3,MBW8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n',
 'UES9157GS5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'UES9157GS5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,GMO5937W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,4QU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,XXQ4064X,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'ONL0812DH1,BER7172M,KUL,LAS,1420565167,1848\n',
 'YMH6360YP0,ATT7791R,AMS,DEN,1420564394,1001\n']
```

with this small sample data I get duplicate data. but with large one I get duplicate and incorrect results too. Any thoughts of what causing this issue

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your code has some issues Check my answer below and see if it helps you @s.m.yousef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes and suggestions to the code

- You would want to compare the item at the same indexes for both arrays, but right now you have 2 for loops which compare each element in both lists.
- You can avoid removing data from `wrong_format`.
- You can split both strings on `,` instead of having explicit indexes, use an generator over the indexes to compare both items and append accordingly

So the updated code will look like

```
corrected = []
correct_format = ['EZC9678QI6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'EZC9678QI6,RUM0422W,MUC,MAD,1420563539,194\n',
 'CKZ3132BR4,XXQ4064B,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'HCA3158QA6,GMO5938W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'JBE2302VO4,VDC9164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'XFG5747ZT9,PME8178S,DEN,PEK,1420564409,1322\n',
 'CDC0302NN5,QHU1140O,CDG,LAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'CYJ0225CH1,YZO4444S,BKK,MIA,1420565330,2027\n',
 'PIT2755XC1,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'IEG9308EA5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'LLZ3798PE3,ULZ8130D,CAN,DFW,1420564983,1683\n',
 'LLZ3798PE3,MBA8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n',
 'PIT2755XC1,SOH3431A,ORD,MIA,1420563649,250\n',
 'XFG5747ZT9,XXQ4064B,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'HCA3158QA6,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'JBE2302VO4,HZT2506M,IAH,AMS,1420564324,1044\n',
 'VZY2993ME1,WSK1289Z,CLT,DEN,1420563542,278\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,TMV7633W,UGK,DXB,1420563958,849\n',
 'EDV2089LK5,ATT7791R,AMS,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',
 'SPR4484HA6,VDC9164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'UES9151GS5,DAU2617A,CGK,SFO,1420564986,1811\n',
 'WBE6935NU3,KJR6646J,IAH,BKK,1420565203,1928\n',
 'CDC0302NN5,XIL3623J,PEK,LAX,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYU2010YH8,JVY9791G,PVG,FCO,1420564561,1189\n']

wrong_format = ['BWI0520BG6,VYW5940P,LAS,SI|,1420565203,1843\n',
 'CKZ3132BR4,RUM0422W,MUC,;AD,1420563539,194\n',
 'CKZ313\\BR4,QHU1140O,CDG,LAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,GMO593[W,LHR,PEK,1420564317,1057\n',
 'CXN7304ER2,VDCP164W,FCO,LAS,1420564698,1276\n',
 'DAZ3029XA0,WPW9201U,DFW,yEK,1420564869,1452\n',
 'HGO4350KK1,QHU1140O,CDG,vAS,1420564498,1133\n',
 'JJM4724RF7,YZO4444S,BKK,MI^,1420565330,2027\n',
 'KKP5277HZ7,VYW5940P,LAS,:IN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'MXU9187YC7,MOO1786A,MAD,]RA,1420563408,184\n',
 'ONL0812DH1,BER7172M,KUL,[AS,1420565167,1848\n',
 'PAJ3974RK1,EWH6301Y,~AN,DFW,1420564967,1683\n',
 'POP2875LH3,MBw8071P,KUL,PEK,1420563856,572\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,SOH3431A,OR8,MIA,1420563649,250\n',
 'PUD8209OG3,XXQ4064%,JFK,FRA,1420563917,802\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,4QU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,HZT2506M,IAH,#MS,1420564324,1044\n',
 'SJD8775RZ4,WSK1289Z,CLT,vEN,1420563542,278\n',
 'SJD8|75RZ4,ULZ8130D,CAN,DFW,1420564983,1683\n',
 'SPR4484HA6,ATT7791R,AM%,DEN,1420564394,1001\n',
 'SPRb484HA6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',
 'UES915*GS5,SQU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n',
 'WBE6935NU$,XOY7948U,ATL,LHR,1420564038,877\n',
 'WTC9125IE5,XIL3623J,PEK,L}X,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYU2010YH8,XIL3623J,PEe,LAX,1420564414,1302\n',
 'WYu2010YH8,FYL5866L,ATL,HKG,1420565140,1751\n',
 'YMH6360YP0,ATT7791R,A;S,DEN,1420564394,1001\n']

def hamming_distance(s1, s2):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))

#Iterate over both lists together
for r, i in zip(correct_format, wrong_format):

    #Split string into words by comma
    li_r = r.split(',')
    li_i = i.split(',')
    #Check all if conditions and append accordingly
    if any(hamming_distance(item_r, item_i) == 1 for item_r, item_i in zip(li_r,li_i)):
        corrected.append(r)

print(corrected)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but unfortunately, I am still getting incorrect results. The reason I am using `wrong_format.remove(i)` is to show the data that wasn't corrected as I have some 0 in my data

Comment: Why do we append `corrected.append(r)` in both the if and else?

Comment: None of them is the same, the wrong format is always 1 character different from correct format. I just noticed that `'SJD8775RZ4,4QU6245R,DEN,FRA,1420564460,1049\n'` is the same in both lists this is a mistake, I apologise for that. I will edit the post

Comment: Your code works perfectly on the list I provided. However, I tried it on the whole list but still getting some errors. I spent the whole day trying to find what is causing this issue and found out that because I am comparing the whole string in each list against the other list.

Comment: I think I need slicing to solve this issue so what expected to happen is if we have this string in the wrong format list `'BWI0520BG6,VYW5940P,LAS,SI|,1420565203,1843\n',` the error here is **SI|**  so once we compare it with a string in the correct format list has the correct character in the same location it should update that error `'EZC9678QI6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n'` so it should be updated and become `'BWI0520BG6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',`

Comment: I have updated the list in the post. Thank you for helping I am still new in python and still need some time to get used to it

Comment: Yes sure. can you please do me a favour? check the updated list I just provided in the post. I read all your comment but still not able to figure it out what is causing this error, I mean why it is still not performing correctly.

Comment: Yes I did that's why I asked you to have a look at the list. what I get is 11 item corrected in the corrected list while it should be 27 and these strings are not even right for example it corrects `'KKP5277HZ7,VYW5940P,LAS,:IN,1420565203,1843\n'` to `'EZC9678QI6,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n',` while it should be corrected to `'KKP5277HZ7,VYW5940P,LAS,SIN,1420565203,1843\n'`

Comment: oh ok, at least I know where my error is. thank you for your help